# ball in the Wasserstein space W_1

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, optimal-transport

Consider the Wasserstein metric W_1 on the set of probability measures on a compact metric space.
I wonder how many balls of radius $\epsilon$ for $\epsilon\in \mathbb R^+$ is needed to cover a ball of size 2 $\epsilon$?
Are there known estimates (lower or upper bound) depending on  $\epsilon$ for this number?

Comment: This number is called the (external) covering number. Maybe this keyword will help you to find relevant information. Some results in this direction (although not quite what you want) are discussed in Chapter 2.4 of this book: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-38438-8_2